# (Access) search text field for strings matching those in another table's field and display these matching records in a subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

Here's my situation,

tbl_products / frm_products

- ID__products
- products__name (short text)
- products__description (short text)

tbl_articles / frm_articles

- ID__articles
- articles__name (short text)
- articles__body (long text)

I have a form bound to tbl_articles containing a subform bound to tbl_products.

What I would like to happen is,

1. once a user enters text into the articles__body field, (using the After Update module)
2. it searches this long text field for any words which match a product name
3. and then (in the subform) displays the matching products.

*For example if the articles__body record that the user is currently viewing contains 'product 1', it will display product 1's record in the subform.*

Perhaps After Update is not appropriate as it needs to appear to remember these matches. For example, if tbl_articles' record 1 matches/displays product 1 on the subform whereas record 2 matches/displays products 2,3 and 4; I need the user to be able to revisit record 1 and see the product 1 match without having to edit the text (and trigger the After Update).

I have no idea where to start with this. It's not a simple *if string contains*, Originally I entertained the idea of something like - Like '* [*in tbl_products, record 1's products__name*] *' repeated for each record (obviously not the correct syntax but simply identifying the process to myself), however this is impractical because the number of strings to match against will grow over time as more products are added.

Any help would be great,
Kind regards

Comment: To give you a head start, Instr() function is your friend...you can search the string like this : InStr("Testing for Product1 in my record", "Product1")

Comment: What purpose will this serve? These tables do not show relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Filter and FilterOn properties. Suggest naming subform container control different from the form it holds, like ctrProducts.

```
Me.ctrProducts.Form.Filter = "InStr('" & Me.articles_body & "', [products_name])>0"
Me.ctrProducts.Form.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: please excuse the lateness of my reply and my ignorance, that appears to be an elegant solution but where do I place the code? In response to the purpose, it\s simply meant as visual checklist - once a piece of text is written in the article, I can see a corresponding checklist criteria has been met, there is no relationship. The idea is that once the body is updated, it searches the products table to see if any of the product's names are amongst the body's text.

Comment: You could try the AfterUpdate event you referenced your question.

Comment: You're fantastic, thank you, it's working, I can see that you're almost at 666 questions answered, rock on

Comment: Glad it worked. And you could make this one more by marking answer accepted if you really liked it. However, not clear what purpose this form/subform arrangement serves.

Comment: No problem, and if I wanted it to search for more than keyword, clearly 'or' doesn't work, I imagine I would have to take a different approach?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but sounds like would be a new question.